# Check if the browsers supports SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to check if browser doesn't supports **SVG**. If yes, I want to add a class to body, something like **noSvg** in body.

Some forums suggested me to add modernizer. However, I am not interested in adding this because its heavy and I don't think its needed for this small task.

Some other forums suggested me to use below javascript

```
function supportsSVG(){
 return !!('createElementNS' in document &&
   document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg').createSVGRect)
}
```

I have tried this and called the function. however, I didn't understood whats really happening.
Any advise will much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you ADD the `noSVG` class to your body and REMOVE it when SVG is supported. This way you're on the safe side when JS is disabled or also not supported for whatever reason (though not supporting SVG is probably the least of your problems in that case...)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Example 1:**

```
if (typeof SVGRect != "undefined") { 
 /* If the browser does support SVG. */ 
} else { 
 /* If the browser does not support SVG. */ 
 var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 bodyElement.className += " noSvg";
}
```

**Example 2:** (Modernizer way of checking SVG)

```
if(!document.implementation.hasFeature('http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image', '1.1')){
  var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  bodyElement.className += " noSvg";
}
```

Comment: i have tried your first example. however, when checked iwth an alert, its working in firefox. But in IE8, those conditions are not checking. What might be the reason?

Comment: SVG is not supported in IE8. Check what are you getting if you do `alert(typeof SVGRect);` on IE8?

Answer (score 0):

This is shorter function, based-on the existence of [SVGRect function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGRect):

```
function supportsSVG() {
    return typeof SVGRect === 'function';
}
```

Comment: === function is not working correctly on ie as this is considered as an object. Muthu Kumaran's solution is correct by checking for undefined.